# How to integrate $\sqrt{x^2}$ using standard integration techniques?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find the indefinite integral of $\sqrt{x^2}$ with respect to $x$ without simplifying it to $|x|$ (which would be wrong in a complex setting)?

What I wanted to know generally how to integrate symbolically a power of a power without simplifying it with the power-rule. Mathematica is giving:

$\int{(x^n)^a}{dx} = \frac{x(x^n)^a}{1+an}$

How does Mathematica find this formula? With substitution, table lookup or another technique?

Comment: Can you please give more information. Do you want a definite or indefinite integral?

Comment: indefinite integral

Comment: You might like to add that to your question...

Comment: In a complex setting $\sqrt{x^2}$ is either $x$ or $-x$, depending on which branch of the square root you choose. Each of these is simple to integrate. If you have a domain where _both_ branches are used at different points, there will not be any antiderivative to find!

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

Method 1: Define $$g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2}$$ and show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(h)}{h}=\sqrt{a^2}$$ for every $a$. That is, $g^\prime(x) = \sqrt{x^2}$. Then invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Method 2 (physics): Integrate
$$\int{\sqrt{x^2+c^2}} = \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{2}c^2\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+c^2})$$
and put $c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2}=x^\frac{2}{2}$$

$$\int \left(x^\frac{2}{2}\right) dx=\frac{2x^\frac{4}{2}}{4}=\frac{x^\frac{4}{2}}{2}$$

$$\therefore \frac{x^\frac{4}{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{2}=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2}}{2}$$

(You don't take out the $x^2$, that's the only difference)

Here's a visual:

[image]

The curved one is the derivative. The slope is negative when $x$ is negative, and positive when $x$ is positive. If you just had $\frac{x^2}{2}$, it would be wrong because it would show that the slope is only positive.

Comment: Not sure whether you can do $\sqrt{x^2}=x^\frac{2}{2}$... Most people would say $x^\frac{2}{2}=x$, even if told $\exists x\neq\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @JMCF125 It's very unconventional but I don't think it's mathematically wrong. Plus, helps visualize the process of taking the integral.

Comment: I guess you're right. +1 then.

Comment: I think this is more sleight-of-hand than an actual derivation. Never mind the $\frac22$ -- how do you argue in a principled way that you can do $\sqrt{x^4}=x\sqrt{x^2}$ in the last step without also allowing $\sqrt{x^2}=x\sqrt{1}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You need it to be negative when $x$ is negative. I showed a picture, check it.

Comment: @Shahar: My point is that it seems that the only rule you follow in the symbolic manipulation is that the allowed steps are whatever you know will lead to the right result. How do you justify these steps _without_ already knowing what the answer you're trying to arrive at is?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I didn't know the answer I'm going to arrive at. I just thought of what the graph looked like in my head. Sketching is one of the steps.

Comment: @Sharar: "I just thought of what the graph looked like in my head." In other words the signs in the calculation steps you show are not because of any principled reason, but because you already know what signs you need the outcome to have.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I used Shahar's Theorem of Doing-this-problem. Principled reason. Works.

Comment: Not according to any sense of "principled" I know of. Works only in the sens of "write down the answer you already know is correct, while showing some irrelevant smoke and mirrors to fool the reader into thinking you're actually deriving it" tautologically produces the right answer -- but is entirely devoid of method, principle, or understanding. $-1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Okay great, awesome. Post your own answer if you want to be so helpful. I want to see if it's "devoid of method, principle, or understanding."
You know, our definition of gravity is also "devoid of method, principle, or understanding." You should go complain about that.

Comment: @Shahar: I'm not the one who claims there is a meaningful way to do what the OP demands.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sure, sure, whatever. Have a nice day.